# Assertion when using const_iterator

Tags: c++, std

I'm testing the use of an interface which has the function foo. Here is my implementation of this function in my mock:

```
class Mock
{
public:
    void foo(Foo::const_iterator begin, Foo::const_iterator end) {
      _begin = begin;
      _end = end;

      ...
    }
    ...
    Foo::const_iterator _begin;
    Foo::const_iterator _end;
};
```

I then have a test which checks if foo has been called:

```
// test that function foo is not called
EXPECT_EQ(mock->_begin, Foo::const_iterator());
```

But this is giving me an assertion in Visual Studio claiming that the iterators are incompatible. I would have expected that _begin would be equal to Foo::const_iterator() if I havent called foo(). Why isn't it?

Comment: Does `operator ==` of `Foo::const_iterator()` allow comparing two default-constructed instances against each other? Making the default-constructed iterator be "invalid" and "different from any iterator" would be a valid choice of semantics.

Comment: @stardust_ How would you compare a member to a type?

Answer (score 1):

Iterators are only comparable if they're pointing to the same container. A default-constructed iterator isn't pointing to a container at all, so it's not compatible with anything by definition.

Comment: Yep, that sums it up. Such iterators have a so-called "singular value", which is the search term that will explain this.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps VS implements their iterator compatibility checks with default constructed iterators treated in such a way that a default constructed iterator is never compatible with any other iterator, even a default constructed one.